# How can I evaluate a JavaScript ES6 module that imports other modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am getting errors trying to create a JavaScript ES6 module from a string of code when it contains imports to other modules. Here is what I have tried so far without success:

1. ```js
   (async () => {
       const moduleJs =
           `import * as OtherModule from './other-module.mjs';
           OtherModule.sayHello();`

       const moduleDataUri = 'data:text/javascript,' + encodeURIComponent(moduleJs);
       const MyModule = await import(moduleDataUri);
   })();
   ```
2. ```js
   (async () => {
       const moduleJs =
           `(async () => {
               const OtherModule = await import('./other-module.mjs');
               OtherModule.sayHello();
            })();`

       const moduleDataUri = 'data:text/javascript,' + encodeURIComponent(moduleJs);
       const MyModule = await import(moduleDataUri);
   })();
   ```

I want to standardize all of my code in modules, so *eval()* and *window.Function()* are not options.

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specifically are the errors and are you using them in the node.js environment ?

Comment: @JonoJames I didn't mention it, but this code will run in browsers.

Comment: Ok so that means that even though Import and exports are in es6 is availible in modern browsers to get them to work you need to use a compiler like babel ... check out this vid on it 


....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xL2dmzdCz8

Comment: Well, in nodejs you could always write the string to a file and import that as a module… But why are you having strings of module code in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi The code comes from the server. This is why I have to evaluate on the client. If this JS code can't be a module, my full code won't be standardized and I won't be able to use module specific features, like [top-level awaits](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await).

Comment: @RosbergLinhares Oops, I was confused. Somehow I thought that data-uri trick would work on the client side, and you were looking for a serverside equivalent.

Comment: For the client side, I would have a look at [system.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and similar module loaders. Then either just use one of those libraries, or the same tricks that they employ. Btw, for sending code from the server to the browser, you could just use an ordinary module file (possibly dynamically generated), importing those works out of the box…